# 2FA is not working with Ubuntu AWS instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ssh, google-authenticator

I worked on setting up 2FA while doing ssh in EC2 instance. But after the setup instance is still not asking for 2FA code and directly logs my user i.e. `ubuntu` into the server.

I did following steps to setup 2FA:

1. Install Google Authenticator PAM module.

   sudo apt install libpam-google-authenticator
2. Add `auth required pam_google_authenticator.so` to `/etc/pam.d/sshd`
3. Restart ssh `sudo systemctl restart sshd.service`
4. Update sshd_config with following:

   `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes PasswordAuthentication no`
5. Run command `google-authenticator`

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue because of other configuration was enabled. PubKeyAuthentication was used instead of authenticator. I change it to `PubKeyAuthentication no` which resolved the issue.